# A hint to help me integrate $ \int {x^5+1\over x^4+x^3+x^2} \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Numerator is of a higher degree than the denominator, so after division I get the following:

$$ \int {x^5+1\over x^4+x^3+x^2} \, dx = \frac 12x^2-x + \int {1\over x^2+x+1} \, dx $$

Comment: complete the square and then do a substitution $x + 1/2 = \sqrt 3/2 \tan u$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \underbrace{x^2+x+1=\left(x^2+x+\frac 1 4 \right)+\frac 3 4}_{\text{completing the square}} = \left( x+\frac 1 2 \right)^2 + \frac 3 4 \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 3 4 \left( \frac 4 3 \left( x+\frac 1 2 \right)^2 + 1 \right) = \frac 3 4 \left( \left( \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}} \right)^2 +1 \right) = \frac 3 4 (u^2 + 1)
\end{align}

and $du=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\,dx$.

And $\displaystyle\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\arctan u + C$.

Comment: i left a hint for op to try. why write up the answer so fast.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Forever grateful for the help I get from this community!

Comment: @abel thanks abel!

Comment: @abel : Sometimes a terse hint is all that's appropriate and sometimes more is in order, depending on---among other things---the students level of ability, which often cannot be gauged based on the posting.  Sometimes I leave a short hint for the poster to fill in the blanks, but I think usually I've done that when it's clear that the poster should be able to do that.

Comment: a minute after the hint is give you post the answer. don't you think that op needs more than a minute to make use of the hint? it does not make sense that you can tell the mathematical level of the op from question alone without any further interaction.